# Sql Query related to student data base:

Tags: mysql

query that display Name of students with count of their real/step brother or Sister enrolled in School

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCTki.png)

Comment: Anybody can help me out with this please?

Comment: Is that an assignement ?

Comment: Show us what yo have done so far. We won't just do your homework for you.

Comment: Please show your effort in what you've tried so far to produce the output you want.

Comment: its a question related to my project could u help me out with this?

Comment: i've tried it but i wont be able to understand it how i can accomplish such output although m a begginer not very good with sql so if u could help me out with this query i would be thankfull please?

Comment: WEi_DBA" i have uploaded the image where my questiontable and required output is given

Comment: please anybody here help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
select TS.studentId,
TS.Sname, 
count(TP.FatherId) as Count 
from Tstudent TS
inner join Tparent TP
on (TS.studentId = TP.FatherId)
group by TS.studentId,TS.Sname
```

Comment: This is not working its shows count 1 for all names of student

Comment: Which column do you reference one table with another?
From his image I imagined TP.FatherId to be his foreign key.
Make sure your parent table has the studentId column and replace it in the query.

Switch TP.FatherId by TP.StudentId